# Running Unity3D on a low specification computer

Tags: windows, specifications, unity3d

I am currently developing an application using Unity3D on my desktop computer for a contract. However, I will be without my desktop computer for an unknown period of time shortly as I am going to be living in some temporary accommodation that has no space for such a large computer.

To bridge the gap, I am looking at buying as cheap a device as possible. The device doesn't have to run Unity3D well, and the game I am developing is for Android so it doesn't even have to run the game itself well either. One of the devices I have found is the ASUS Transformer Book T100, but whilst it meets the [minimum requirements](http://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements) my experience has told me that this does not necessarily mean the program will run at all.

**My question is, would an ASUS Transformer Book T100 (or similar) be able to run Unity3D and all of its features*?**

I understand that the minimum specifications imply could, but I am hoping someone has tried doing so with a similar device who can share their experiences of what it's like in reality rather than in theory.

---

**Update 1 - Statistics**

While continuing my own research, I have found this resource for [Unity3D editor hardware statistics](http://stats.unity3d.com/editor/cpu.html) (in case the link breaks, Intel Atom show up as 0.7% of users). This shows the people have at least tried to run it on Intel Atom processors and their kin, but for all I know the users may have discontinued the use of that device because it was unusable.

---

<sub>* I'm trying to keep this as objective and suitable for the site as possible, if it isn't please leave a comment and I'll edit the question as best I can.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cost is the issue, why not buy a used, more powerful laptop?

**Source:**

I have successfully run Unity3D with all its features with no issue whatsoever on a 2011 Dell Inspiron n5110 with a second-gen i3 and 3 GB ram.

You can probably find a similar model for $200 depending on your area.

Comment: You probably would want at least 4 gigs of ram though.

Comment: That's a great idea, thank you! Do you have any information regarding the Atom though? I'll still vote this up since it's useful.

Comment: The Atom won't be good for Unity. i3 processors not only have the CPU power, but the GPUs that come integrated are much more powerful than Atom. Developing on Unity3D, you will be using a lot of GPU so I don't think Atom would work very well under the load.